# Servlet/Javascript chunking

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am trying to design a system from scratch where I want to load lines of text through a servlet. The production of lines takes some time. As such, I want to be able to display them incrementally in my browser as they arrive, a few at a time. I want to send one request from javascript to my servlet.

I have been researching this and I cannot find a solution. What do I need to do in my servlet to flush a few lines at a time? What do I need to do in my javascript to retrieve these flushed lines until the end of the stream? Is it possible, or do I need to paginate with multiple requests to my servlet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, you can use a combination of the request's `Reader`, and a combination of the response's `Writer` and `flushBuffer` method.

The idea is to read a chunk of data off of the incoming stream, e.g. using `getLine`, then process the line in some way on the server, then write some chunk of information out to the response using `getWriter.write` followed by `flushBuffer`.

For example:

```
override def service(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse) {

  val r = req.getReader

  def echoLines: Unit =
    Option(r.readLine) foreach { line => // read a chunk from the request

      // simulate slow server-side processing
      Thread.sleep(1000)

      // write a chunk to the response
      res.getWriter.write("read line: " + line + "\n")

      // force the response buffer to be written to the client
      res.flushBuffer

      // repeat until the request is completely processed
      echoLines
    }

  echoLines
}
```

You can test this with curl (make sure to use the `-N` option):

```
curl -N -X POST --data-binary @test.txt localhost:8080
```

On the client side, you can have your code react when the XHR `readyState` is `3` (processing request):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function go() {
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 3 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var out = document.getElementById('out');
            out.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
          }
        }
        xhr.open('POST', '/echo', true);
        xhr.send('hello\nworld\n\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="go()">
    <pre id="out"></pre>
  </body>
</head>
```

Comment: Got it. How about javascript? How do I get partials?

Comment: Updated to include a JavaScript example.

Comment: I put together a complete example (with a demo) [here](https://github.com/earldouglas/xwp-template/tree/chunky#chunked-http-with-ajax-and-scala).

Comment: Thanks; I'm glad you find it useful!