# Read large json data returned from java servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

Servlet returns about 4000 rows as json object.

Without any processing in javascript, browser is not responsive for a second or two.
When that data is processed in "for loop" ...not responsive for about 4 seconds.

Is that json object to large for browser to handle...even without processing is not responsive?

Any idea how to solve that?...Thanks.

Comment: You need really the 4000 rows? , I guess there's a problem with the design of your application

Comment: Are you retrieving the data asynchronously?

Comment: Hm...yes..that are "elements" that are selected with click...all them must be visible

Comment: You'll need to periodically flush the response output buffer from the servlet, and watch on the client side for `readyState == 3`.  [Here's an example](https://github.com/earldouglas/xwp-template/tree/chunky#chunked-http-with-ajax-and-scala) of this I wrote to answer a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095434/servlet-javascript-chunking/23113819#23113819).

Comment: It seems like a good idea...thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If it is slower than you are happy with, you're probably going to have to chunk the data.

Only fetch the data that is going to be showed on page load and then request the rest as needed.  If it's for a grid, load the first 20 records and then retch what is needed per request.

If you need ALL of the data
1) only fetch the data that shows on the page
2) load the rest of the data in the background
3) merge the data behind the scenes

Comment: Hm...that is the main problem...all that must be shown on page...as list of "elements"..

Comment: The most important issue is browser not responsive....with only ajax call...without any data processing